# How can I simply run "forminput" application in wicket example page using eclipse and tomcat

Tags: eclipse, wicket, tomcat7

I am new to wicket and dont know how to use mvn, i want to run;  http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/forminput/?2  application. In the link there source codes, so how can i create project and call the jars, libraries and get work the project. Which steps should i follow. Thanks for your helps. Soso

Answer (score 0):

I really think you need to start by learning Maven. It is really simple to learn the basics and it will help you for a big part of your future projects. The time you'll spend learning Maven will allow you to understand your future framework and model your projects the right way. I think it requires less time to understand Maven than a whole discussion here explaining how to run it properly in Eclipse.

Basically, all you will need to do is run `mvn jetty:run` in the folder of your clone of wicket-examples to get started. Once you got there, grab a tutorial or two explaining the basics of Maven in order to really get started.

Comment: Mr Cedric, First thanks for your response, for now, if you direct me how to run the source  code i really appreciate it, mvn says 3 parameters write these and this is your structure but how can import sources, find libs ext. It is impoortant for me to know how can i run this example and tomorrow other ones, anyway many can learn so much from this topic. Soso

Comment: Basically a mvn package will build the war of your application in the target directory. You can deploy it in your tomcat then.